# Проблема с socket.io и React

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, reactjs

Делаю чат с использованием React, react-router, expressjs и socket.io. В ходе работы чата возникла проблема. Есть форма и в ней поле ввода сообщения, по нажатии enter сообщение отправляется на сервер нормально, но клиентский метод on(), который срабатывает, когда с сервера пришло сообщение, выводит сообщения как-то странно. То есть, если отправить первое сообщение на сервер, то оно отображается нормально, но если отправить второе на сервер, то в ответе приходит уже два одинаковых сообщения, то есть с каждым отправленным сообщением в ответ с сервера приходит на одно сообщение больше (см. скрин.). код на клиенте (компонент React'а):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
export default class Chat extends Component {
addMessage (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    window.socket.emit('chat message', e.target.message.value);

    e.target.message.value = '';

    window.socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
        document.getElementById('chatMsgList').innerHTML += '<li>' +  msg + '</li>';
    });
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <ul id="chatMsgList"></ul>
            <form id="chatForm" onSubmit={this.addMessage}>
                <input autoComplete="off" type="text" id="chatInp" name="message" className="form-control"/>
            </form>
        </div>
          )
}
```

[image: Листинг сообщений (введено только 5 сообщений, но с сервера пришло больше)]

И еще проблема с тем же чатом. Если открыть чат в двух браузерах и писать сообщения, они не отобразятся в другом окне до тех пор, пока что-либо не будет отправлено из открывшегося окна, вот только тогда, если написать опять что-то в первом окне, то оно уже придет во второе. В общем тоже странно как-то. Либо я на сервере что-то не так сделал, либо какая то проблема на стороне клиента, то есть в React
Код на сервере:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

(function initWebpack() {
    var express = require('express');
    const webpack = require('webpack');
    const webpackConfig = require('./webpack/common.config');
    const compiler = webpack(webpackConfig);

    app.use(require('webpack-dev-middleware')(compiler, {
         noInfo: true, publicPath: webpackConfig.output.publicPath,
}));

app.use(require('webpack-hot-middleware')(compiler, {
    log: console.log, path: '/__webpack_hmr', heartbeat: 10 * 1000,
}));

    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));
})();

app.get(/.*/, function root(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
        io.emit('chat message', msg);
    });
});

http.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('Server on 3000 listening');
});
```

код index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="public/styles/common.css">
</script>
<title>React app</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="/dist/bundle.js"></script>
<script>
window.socket = io();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Надеюсь на вашу помощь в том, чтобы заставить чат работать

Comment: насчёт не нашёл в интренете примера. Вот видео где в реальном времени показывается создание приложения : React real-time with Socket.io. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9FPkN6ETqes - Citrusbyte presents: Making React real-time with Socket.io - Eddie Zaneski

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам достаточно вынести код

```
window.socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    document.getElementById('chatMsgList').innerHTML += '<li>' +  msg + '</li>';
});
```

за пределы функции `addMessage()` (но после создания самого сокета).

В чем проблема:

1. Открывается сокет, но клиент не подписывается на сообщения, пока не отправит сообщение сам `window.socket.on('chat message')//на клиенте`. Если после открытия сокета вызвать данный метод, сообщения должны будут отображаться без отправки первого сообщения.
2. При каждом вызове функции  `addMessage()` навешивается дополнительный обработчик `window.socket.on('chat message')//на клиенте`, и **каждый из них** добавляет сообщение на страницу.

Решение изложено выше.